# JSP duplicate local variable while deploying tomcate

Tags: jsp

```
<% User loginUser = (User)session.getAttribute("loginUser");
int userlevel = Integer.parseInt( (request.getAttribute("userlevel")).toString());
String status = (String)request.getAttribute("formstatus");
%>
```

based on userlevel I have to include different file on the same page
for example

```
 <% if(userlevel > 2){ %>
                                          <%@include file="apr-part3.jsp"%>
                                    <%}else{ %>
                                        You have not permission to view this part
                                    <% } %>
```

in `apr-part3.jsp` page some part is common for user 3 and 4
I have to check user level in `apr-part3.jsp` as follows again
in `apr-part3.jsp`

```
<% User loginUser = (User)session.getAttribute("loginUser");
int userlevel = Integer.parseInt( (request.getAttribute("userlevel")).toString());
String status = (String)request.getAttribute("formstatus");
%>
<% if(userlevel==3){
     do something
}if(userlevel==4){
do something
}
```

Everything runs fine in eclipse  but when deploying on tomcat apache
it gives the error

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 2 in the jsp file: /jsp-page/apr-part3.jsp
>   Duplicate local variable loginUser

How can I avoid these errors

Answer (score 4):

The `@include` will include the JSP during compile time. So it basically ends up in the same block of Java code. You have 2 options:

- Use `<jsp:include>` instead.
- Get rid of the redeclarations in `apr-part3.jsp`.

---

Better yet, is to just use JSTL/EL.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${userlevel > 2}">
        <jsp:include page="apr-part3.jsp" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        You have not permission to view this part.
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Equivalently, the request attribute `loginUser` is available by `${loginUser}` and `status` by `${formstatus}`. See also [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 1):

This is a small aside as it relates to your question header but not your example body of code.

This problem can occur when using tags with scriptlet too. I know, I know, it's not best practice but, it happens. At least this is the case in WebLogic 10.2.3.

The situation arises if you have a tag that adds a variable to the page context for consumption within the jsp, such as:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    String myvar = ...;
    pageContext.setAttribute("myvar", myvar);

    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}
```

If you then declare a var within scriptlet within the using jsp with the same name as the attribute name on the context then you get a duplicate local variable error on jsp compilation. For instance:

```
<%
    String myvar = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("myvar");
    ...
 %>
```

The reason being that the jsp's compiled servlet contains injected tag code and boilerplate code that actually already creates a "String myvar" with the value of the attribute taken from the page context. So, your scriptlet declaration is actually superfluous as the data is already available.

Check the pre-compiled servlet to check (WEB-INF/weblogic.xml jsp-descriptor config in your webapp).